# CSS for a chat page: 1 column for users list and 1 column for the chat

Tags: html, css

I am working on an html page that has a chat feature.

I want to have a chat box which will have a user list box with a height equals to the height of browser or fit the height of the browser.

The list of users will be positioned on the left and will be scrollable. Messages will be positioned on the right of this block like we see on Facebook.

Scrolls are working well with a fixed height. However when I change that height to 100% then it just display all the block and add a scroll to the browser if the window is too small.

This is actually what I have:

HTML:

```
<html>
<head> ... </head>
<body>
    <div id="global">
        <header> ... </header>
        <nav> ... </nav>
        <div id="contenu">
            <div id="conversationsList">
                <ul id="ulConversations">
                    <li> User 1 </li>
                    <li> User 2 </li>
                    <li> User 3 </li>
                    <li> User 4 </li>
                    <li> User 5 </li>
                    <li> User 6 </li>
                    <li> User 7 </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div id="conversation">
                <ul id="messagesList">
                    <li> Message 1 </li>
                    <li> Message 2 </li>
                    <li> Message 3 </li>
                    <li> Message 4 </li>
                    <li> Message 5 </li>
                    <li> Message 6 </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <p class="clearBoth"></p>
        <footer> ... </footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.clearBoth{
    clear: both;
}

html {
   height: 100%;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#global{
    width: 968px;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 10px;
    position: relative;
}

header{
    padding: 20px 34px 0;
    height: 110px;
}

nav{
    clear: both;
    width: 968px;
    height: 45px;
}

#contenu{
    width: 920px;
    padding: 20px 20px 60px 20px; /* padding bottom 60px for the footer */
}

#conversationsList{
    width: 215px;
    height: 100%;
    float:left;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
}

#conversationsList #ulConversations{
    height: 400px;
    overflow: auto;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
}

#conversationsList #ulConversations li{
    clear: both;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 60px;
}

#conversation{
    width: 700px;
    float: left;
}

#conversation #messagesList{
    height: 340px;
    overflow: auto;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    width: 700px;
    border: solid 1px #eaa9c7;
}

footer{

    width: 968px;    
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    height:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
}
```

In short I want a Facebook styled Chat box. Please help me with a good solution.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

JSfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/2cQm7/1/

I can't find a CSS solution, but here is a JQuery workaround:

```
<script>
    var height;
    $(document).ready( function () {
    var initialh  = $( window ).height() - 30;
      $("#conversation").css("height" , initialh + 'px');

     $( window ).resize(function() {
        height = $( window ).height() - 30;
      $("#conversation").css("height" , height + 'px');
     });
    });
</script>
```

Here's the CSS for the footer and other adjustments:

```
  position:relative;
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    clear:both;
```

Let me know if it works for you.

The jquery keeps the height fixed to the bottom but leaves space for the footer and the footer is sticking to the bottom of the layout.

Comment: I missed the quote when I wrote the post sorry. However in my html code the quote is present and I have the same problem. I also modified the footer thank you for the tip ;)

Comment: Now I modified the footer, when I add height 100% for conversations then they are all displayed and there is no scroll anymore.

Comment: I'll have a look at the footer now. Try putting the JS code in and remove the footer for now, see how it works

Comment: Ok, this footer wouldn't work with this page. I edited my initial answer, look at the JSfiddle. I think it works the way you want it to!

Comment: I thought it was possible to adjust it only with css but your solution is working weel, I just need to find a solution for the footer now. Thanks you.